# How to select one column without one specified row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with three columns, id, username and password.
I want to display all usernames, without one username: "HEHE". How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, I have tried unset, and != after WHERE..but not works. Thankfully, the answers below works perfectly for me. Thank all of you.

Comment: ,appreciate you mark the correct answer[which worked for you],so that it helps others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT username FROM your_table WHERE username <> 'HEHE';
```

***or***

```
SELECT username FROM your_table WHERE username != 'HEHE';
```

***or***

```
SELECT username FROM your_table WHERE username NOT LIKE 'HEHE';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select username
from your_table
where username <> 'HEHE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT username
FROM TableName
WHERE username<>'HEHE'
```

**OR**

Using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT username
FROM TableName
WHERE username NOT LIKE '%HEHE%'
```

It will remove records whose username contains 'HEHE'. For example: MHEHESD.

Answer (score 0):

use [Not equal <>](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

```
SELECT username
FROM YourTableName
WHERE username<>'HEHE'
```

or

```
SELECT username
 FROM YourTableName
 WHERE username !='HEHE'
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I am new to PHP and never seen the <> before in any language..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username FROM tableName WHERE username<>'HEHE';
SELECT username FROM tableName WHERE username NOT LIKE 'HEHE';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT username
 FROM <TableName>
 WHERE username !='HEHE';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
SELECT * from your_table where username !='HEHE';
```